# elasticsearch-ruby: transforms

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-ruby

We can read into the [elasticsearch-ruby CHANGELOG](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md) (Vewsion 7.7.0) That we have New API Endpoints availables. Transforms included. [Here they are](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/tree/main/elasticsearch-api/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/transform).

We are using elasticsearch-ruby 7.15.0. But don't know how to use it.

Here is my example...

```rb
require 'elasticsearch'

elasticsearch = Elasticsearch::Client.new(
  cloud_id: '******',
  user: '******',
  password: '******',
  log: false
)

elasticsearch.transform.stop_transform transform_id: 'my_transform'
```

But we get an error...

```sh
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/elasticsearch-7.15.0/lib/elasticsearch.rb:43:in `method_missing': undefined method `transform' for #<Elasticsearch::Client:0x0000556a2ad72bb8> (NoMethodError)
```

The code it's inside the folder /lib/elasticsearch/api/actions. Just as indices.

We can use indices like that...

```rb
if elasticsearch.indices.exists? index: 'mi_index'
  <do what ever we want>
end
```

We can't find nothing into de doc. https://rubydoc.info/gems/elasticsearch-api/Elasticsearch/API

So, how can we use the transform endopints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Thanks to @picandocodigo.](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/issues/1554)

> The elasticsearch-xpack gem was deprecated and its endpoints (like
> those under the transform namespace) were merged into
> elasticsearch-api, but only for main and the 8.x version. In 7.x
> versions of the client, you still need to install and require the
> elasticsearch-xpack gem. You can see the code [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/tree/7.15/elasticsearch-xpack/lib/elasticsearch/xpack/api/actions/transform) for 7.15.
>
> So you need to do something like:

```rb
require 'elasticsearch'
require 'elasticsearch/xpack'

client = Elasticsearch::Client.new
client.transform.stop_transform(transform_id: 'my_transform' )
```